# VBA why can't I run a macro from a different document?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a huge macro and part of it does:

```
Dim wbMain As Workbook: Set wbMain = ActiveWorkbook
Dim wbData As Workbook: Set wbData = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\data\MAC DOC.xlsm")
wbData.Activate
Application.Run ("'" & wbData.Name & "'!Macro_NEW")
```

But, on doing `.Run` it fails to run the macro even though `whatworkbook = ActiveWorkbook.Name` returns the same as `wbData.Name` and even trying it manually with `Application.Run ("'MAC DOC.xlsm'!Macro_NEW")` does the same thing.

> Run-time error: 1004
>   Cannot run the macro: "MAC_DOC.xlsm!Macro_NEW". The macro may not be avaliable in this workbook or all macros may be disabled

Why is this coming up when the macro *does* exist in the `MAC DOC.xlsm`
Any advice welcome.

Comment: Try what Erik posted below, I'm in consensus with it. I believe that would fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the full path to name the macro, which is

```
WorkbookName!VBAProjectName.ModuleName.MacroName
```

FYI, The default project name is `VBAProject` and the default module name is `Module1`.

(You might also consider `wbData.FullName` instead of `wbData.Name`.)

[Also, if you know that the macro is always in the active workbook I think you can leave off the prefix and just use the simple macro name -- but we don't always want to activate other workbook, so then use the full macro path name.]

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs fine for me. Make sure that Macro_New is in a standard module, not a sheet or ThisWorkbook module.